# Looping VBA code to check for highlighted cells

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I would like a code to check every cell in range A1:A14 and if the cell is highlighted say yes or no in column B.

[image].

```
Sub highlighted()

 Dim rng As Range
 Dim c As Range

    Set rng = ActiveCell

    For Each c In rng

      If c.Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Yes"

    Exit Sub

    End If

  Next c

End Sub
```

This code works sucsessfully for one single highlighted cell, how can I get it to loop through my desired range, and also include the "no" for non-highlighted cells?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the code. Read the comments and adjust according your needs.

```
Sub highlighted()

    Dim evaluatedRange As Range
    Dim evaluatedCell As Range

    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rangeAddress As String

    ' Adjust these two parameters
    sheetName = "Sheet1"                         ' Sheet name where the range is located
    rangeAddress = "A1:A14"

    Set evaluatedRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range(rangeAddress)

    ' This will loop through each cell in the range
    For Each evaluatedCell In evaluatedRange

        ' Evaluates if the cell has a pattern (what ever it is)
        If evaluatedCell.Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then

            ' Set the value of the cell next to the one evaluated (same row - rowOffset:=0 but next column columnOffset:=1) to Yes
            evaluatedCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value = "Yes"

            ' Exit Sub -> This would exit the whole process, so if you want to evaluate the whole range, just delete this line
        Else

            evaluatedCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Value = "No"

        End If

    Next evaluatedCell

    MsgBox "Process finished!" ' -> alert the user...

End Sub
```

If this is what you need, remember to mark the answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you could simply do:

```
Sub highlighted()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim c As Range

   Set rng = Range("A1:A14")
   For Each c In rng
        If c.Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then 
            c.Range("A1").Offset(0,1).Value = "Yes"
        End If
   Next c
End Sub
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248) for tips on avoiding unneeded `Select`s